# Run wordpress Multisite on sibling subdomains?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on setting up a wordpress-mu site. Here are the conditions

http://example.com is occupied by the main site.

The intranet will be used for sites like

intra.example.com(main site)
blog.example.com

In my current setup

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
```

This makes it possible to log in to all sites, however the links to all network-admin-pages, such as `/wp-admin/network/` etc. link to  `example.com/wp-admin/network/`. It should be intra.example.com/wp-admin/network/. If I write that manually I will get redirected.

if I set

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'intra.example.com');
```

The login to blog.example.com will not work. If I put in the incorrect password I get the error

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

If I put in the correct username/password I simply get redirected to the loginpage again, with no error-code. My guess is that this is due to some issues with the cookies.

Comment: Thanks concerning MU(updated). I don't want multiple adresses, I just want one: intra.example.com/wp-admin/network/, however, I can't use that intra as my DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, because then, the login to blog.example.com  doesn't work.

Comment: Paste the Multisite block of your `wp-config.php`. Also, for me it's not clear: MS is installed in `example.com`, right? Is it the site with ID == 1?